# Administrator Policy blocking Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-10

I have IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15. I am not the admin of my Windows 10 desktop, but I have been trying extremely hard to get IntelliJ to work. I got the administrator to allow the installation of IntelliJ, but it would not let me run the program. Once I run it, IntelliJ will have an error message reading something like this: 
Administrator Policy 1% is restricted by Administrator Policy 2%.

It gives no help whatsoever in how to fix this, but I realized there is this problem for many other of my Java-using applications. I have poured many days trying to research and fix this problem, but I have found no success. Please help. Thank You!

Comment: You need full admin privileges, plain and simple.  Speak to your admin about getting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, if you extract the JDK (instead of installing it), you can get away with "not having to install java", which some administrators dislike.